# Is there a way to (de)serialize a Java enum to/from YAML?

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I am trying to serialize and deserialize a Java object that contains an enum to/from YAML representation. I'm trying to use the Jackson (`com.fasterxml.jackson`) package to do this.

I keep getting this exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.beastcode.devops.prometheusbroker.domain.Metric$Type` from String "counter": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [GAUGE, COUNTER]
```

I assume I need some sort of adapter or converter, but don't know what's available (if anything) for YAML.

For reference:

Metric.java:

```
public class Metric {

  public enum Type {
    COUNTER, GAUGE
  }

  private String           name;
  private String           description;
  private Type             type;
  private List<String>     labels;
  private List<MetricData> data;

  // getters/setters removed
}
```

data.yaml:

```
---
name: gitlab_pipeline_success_total
description: "blah blah blah"
type: counter
labels:
  - project
  - somethingElse
data:
```

Parser.java:

```
public class Parser {

  private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

  public void parse() throws StreamReadException, DatabindException, IOException {
    Metric m = mapper.readValue(new File("data.yaml"), Metric.class);
  }

}
```

Comment: case probably matters - from data.yaml - try changing `type: counter` to `type: COUNTER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Jackson uses the enum's `valueOf` method. That's case sensitive.

You can easily change this by adding a static method annotated with `@JsonCreator`:

```java
public class Metric {

    public enum Type {
        COUNTER, GAUGE;

        @JsonCreator
        public static Type getType(String value) {
            return valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
        }

        // optional, for serialization
        @JsonValue
        public String value() {
            return name().toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    // rest omitted
}
```

Comment: Is `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonValue` going to work for YAML?

Comment: I've just tested it to make sure, but yes. The `@JsonXXX` annotations (also `@JsonProperty`) also work for YAML (and probably other formats as well). These are not just for JSON but for Jackson in general, the name probably is chosen because Jackson is mostly used for JSON.